# How to hide or mask the loggers(Database connect details) which is generate by Hibernate's API

Tags: hibernate

In application log file, i have observed that hibernate logging apis are printing the Database connection information like password, so is there any way to hide or mask such sensitive information?

eg. HHH000046: Connection properties:Connection properties: {user=<####>, password=<####>}

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved now, its required an explicit entry in log4j.xml as follows-

```
<logger name="**org.hibernate**" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Audit"/>     
</logger>
```